# PHP fopen() with "w" creates duplicate entries in directory

Tags: php, directory, duplicates, fopen, unlink

I run a PHP program to create a number of files. That program uses fopen() like this:

```
$outputfile = fopen($outfilename, "w") or die("Unable to open file $outfilename");
fwrite($outputfile,$txtstr);
fclose($outputfile);'
```

My list of files has duplicate entries. When I run the program, I expect it to overwrite the duplicate entries. It does that correctly but there is an undesirable side-effect. The duplicate entries show up in the directory. I can see the duplicate entries when I run the PHP

```
scandir($mydirectory);
```

and echo the entries.

Using FTP to view the directory, I don't see any duplicate names but I know they are there because even after I delete all the "visible" files, I can't delete the directory itself ("directory is not empty").

I've tried using "x" on the fopen() and that worked (to prevent the duplicate entries) but instead of overwriting the file, it retains the data from the first occurrence which is not what I want.

I've tried putting

```
if (file_exists($outfilename)) {
  unlink($outfilename);
}
```

before using the fopen() hoping that this would delete the file first but that still resulted in duplicate entries in the directory.

The directory is corrupted so I can't get rid of it. At the moment I am just renaming it so I can run another test with a clean directory. But I'm creating a lot of clutter. What I really need is a solution to overwrite the  file contents without creating duplicate entries in the directory.

Comment: How are you echoing the `scandir`? Also can you show how the duplicates are shown?

Comment: I was echoing in a foreach loop:     foreach($files as $x => $x_value) {
      echo $x_value;
      echo '<br />';
    }

Comment: The problem has mysteriously disappeared! GoDaddy has done something to the hidden files to make them 'visible' to me both in FTP and in their File Manager. My guess is that they changed the owner or permissions on these files. I'd like to mark this item as closed since the conditions have changed and I'm unlikely to be able to repeat.